# location.replace and base tag : strange behavior in IE

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, url

I have this base tag in my page :

```
<base href="http://localhost:8080/application/module/jsp/Vues/">
```

When I test *location.replace* in Chrome, it behaves as expected, using the base url :

```
location.replace(test)
=> http://localhost:8080/application/module/jsp/Vues/test
```

But IE seems to ignore the base URL and to use instead the current location :

```
location.replace(test)
=> http://localhost:8080/application/module/jsp/test
```

Any ideas why IE is ignoring the base tag? How to make the two browser have the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue today. After a long research I gave up and set the absolute URL instead.

```
var baseUrl = $('base').attr('href');
location.replace(baseUrl + relativeUrl);
```

or

```
location.replace(location.origin + baseUrl + relativeUrl);
```

if u have relative path in your base element.